# Checking out of bounds for attributedSubstringFromRange

Tags: ios

I have simple method like this.

```
NSAttributedString *aStr = [self.attributedText attributedSubstringFromRange:range];
```

But sometimes, it show error 'out of bounds'. How can I check beforehand? Do I only check .length ? Is there alternative way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the following check:

```
range.location + range.length <= self.attributedText.length
```